# How to calculate a probability that a time series takes values in a given interval?

Tags: time-series, arma

So I have a time series $X_t$, where $X_t$ is the number of sales of a product at day t. I would like to be able to calculate some probability like this

$P(X_t>10)$ for $t \in [5,20]$ : this means that over 15 days I have sold more than 10 items.

This might be a dummy question and I know it strongly depends on what model I use for $X_t$. But what sort of approach could I take, lets say for example that $X_t$ follows an ARMA model.

Comment: I suggest using simulation. Estimate the ARMA model and then simulate with estimated coefficients. Calculate proportion of simulations satisfying your condition. This will be your probability. This approach for example is used for estimating the confidence intervals for ARIMA processes.

Comment: Also, does it mean that you have sold more than 10 items for *all* days or *at least one* day? And you wish to look at the unconditional probability, so not condition on where you were at, say, $t=4$?

Comment: I would mean that I have sold more than 10 for all days.